# form_for won't pass value of select field to controller? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that is supposed to delete an `option` from the `select` tag that it's in when the form is submitted. However, even though the form is able to call the correct `destroy` action in my `UnitTypes` controller, I keep getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UnitTypesController#destroy

Couldn't find UnitType with 'id'=
```

It *appears* that the value from my `form_for` is not passing the value over to the controller.

I have tried many different ways to get this to work, but it seems that `form_for` and use of the `:method => :delete` together are don't function very well.

I have tried passing in junk string values for the form to "please" the url's need for a parameter, but that has also not worked.

Here's what I have:

**Route:**
`resources :unit_types`

---

**The Form**

```
.panel.panel-default
  = form_for @unitType, :html => { :method => :delete, remote: true } do |f|
    .panel-heading
      %strong Remove Unit Type
    .panel-body
      = f.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(UnitType.all, "id", "name"), { :prompt => "Delete..." }, class: "form-control unit-type-select", id: "remove-unit-type-field"
    .panel-footer
      = f.submit "Remove", :id => "remove-unit-type", :class => "btn btn-default"
```

---

**UnitTypesController**

```
class UnitTypesController < ApplicationController

def create
    @unitType = UnitType.new(unit_type_params)

    if @unitType.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Failed to create new unit type."
    end
end

def destroy
    @unitType = UnitType.find(params[:id])

    if @unitType.destroy
        respond_to :js
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error trying to delete the unit type."
    end
end

private def unit_type_params
    params.require(:unit_type).permit(:name)
end

end
```

Comment: Your form sends params[: unit_type][:id] and params[:id] is nil. You don't need to modify unit_type_params, but you should do `@ unitType = UnitType.find(params[:unit_type][:id])`

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it that way over strong parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the parameter via `unit_type_params`:

```
def destroy
    @unitType = UnitType.find(unit_type_params[:id]) #change here
    # ...
end

private def unit_type_params
    params.require(:unit_type).permit(:id, :name) # and here
end
```

That's because of Rails [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Please let me know if it still doesn't work. There also might be another problem with `params`.

Comment: Perfect! I am surprised I couldn't find an answer over Google for the last two days on this. Thank you very much, this just made me very happy.

Comment: For the first time, it took me a few days too :) You are welcome.